# Compose multiply Arrangement

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, modifier

ChatGPT says there is a multy arrangement available but I can't find it. How can I do it?

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        .arrange(
            firstArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            secondArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        )
) {
    // Add child elements here
}
```

I need to center and space chips within a `FlowRow`. If I use `Spacer`, there are extra gaps occur:

```
FlowRow (horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center){
    items.forEach {
                    FilterChip(),
                    Spacer(Modifier.width(16.dp))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(Dimens.paddingNormal, Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
```